# Execute shell script with different interpreter

Tags: java, python, jsch

I am trying to execute python script using a [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/), what I want is to run the python script from a **.sh** file using a different interpreter (shebang).

Here is the content of my shell script file (**fileExec.sh**):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print 'hello from python'
```

It looks like the shebang cannot be changed since I getting:

> bash : print command is not found

Here is my Java code:

```
session = newSessionFor(user, host, port);
Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

File shFile = new File("fileExec.py");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(shFile);
writer.write(shebang + "\n");
writer.write(command);
writer.close();

PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(shFile);
printWriter.println(shebang);
printWriter.println(command);
printWriter.close();

((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(shFile));
```

Answer (score 1):

The shebang is only used by the OS when executing a file.

You are not executing a file, you are basically copy-pasting the contents of a python file onto your shell prompt.

If you don't want to store and execute a file on the server, you can run a Python command from a shell with `python -c yourcommand`. Here's how that looks in a terminal, feel free to try:

```
user@host ~$ python -c 'print "hello world"'
hello world
```

To do this in your program, add a method to escape an arbitrary string in shells:

```
static String escapeForShell(String s) {
  return "'" + s.replaceAll("'", "'\\\\''") + "'";
}
```

then run

```
((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("python -c " + escapeForShell(command));
```

where `String command = "print 'hello from python'";`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very good with Java, but it could be checking the file extension before checking the hashbang. You should change the file to `fileExec.py` to make sure, or just `fileExec`.

(You also appear to be calling the wrong file in the java code?)

Answer (score 0):

File extensions should not be relevant, but for consistency you usually don't call a python script `fileExec.sh`.

If you test `fileExec.sh` from command line, assuming you set the execute permission on it, it should work:

```
$ chmod +x fileExec.sh
$ ./fileExec.sh
hello from python
```

However, there's no need to rely on shebang and changing file permissions, just do:

```
$ python fileExec.sh
```

from the command line and from your java program too

```
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("/usr/bin/python /path/to/fileExec.sh");
```